# Parallel.For with date time

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

OK this code is a bit meta but it roughly explains how i have it now and what i want to achieve.

```
specialObject{
  DateTime date;
  int number;
}

var startDate = Lowest date in the list;
var endDate = Hightest date int the list;

List<SpecialObject> objs = (list from database where date > startDate and date < endDate)
//A list with alot of dates and numbers, most of the dates are the same. List contains roughly 1000 items, but can be more and less.

for(var date = startDate; date < endDate; date = date.AddDay(1){
    listItem = objs.Where(x => x.Day = date).Sum(x => x.alotOfNUmbers);
}
```

Now since i don't care what day i calculate first, i thought i could do this.

```
Parallel.For(startDate, endDate, day => {
     listItem = objs.Where(x => x.Day = date).Sum(x => x.alotOfNUmbers);
}
```

But how do i make it step dates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a Range and iterate over it with Parallel.ForEach :

```
// not tested
var days = Enumerable
     .Range(0, (endDate-startDate).Days)   // check the rounding
     .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

Parallel.ForEach(days, day => ....)
```

Alternatively, you could use PLinq over the original source, probably faster. Roughly:

```
 // not tested
 var sums = objs.AsParallel().GroupBy(x => x.date).Select(g => g.Sum(i => i.number));
```

Answer (score 1):

All the overloads of [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) take two integer variables for start and end. I also don't see any version which would support something like a step so you can't just use the tick count of a `DateTime` as the loop variable.

But it should be easy to use a `Parallel.ForEach` instead, when you create an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` as the source sequence.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days) 
                       .Select(t => startDate.AddDays(t));
```

Add +1 to the `count` parameter if the `endDate` is inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a few days search i figured if i placed all days in an array and "whiled" through it. It gives a pretty good result. With code easy to read

```
        var start = new DateTime(2014, 09, 09);
        var end = new DateTime(2014, 10, 01);

        var listOfDays = new List<DateTime>();

        int i = 0;

        for (var day = start; day < end; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            listOfDays.Add(day);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(listOfDays.ToArray(), currentDay =>
        {
            for (var d = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, currentDay.Month, currentDay.Day, 0, 0, 0); d < new DateTime(currentDay.Year, currentDay.Month, currentDay.Day, 23, 59, 59); d = d.AddSeconds(5))
            {
                var str = "Loop: " + i + ", Date: " + d.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            i++;

        });
        Console.Read();
```